# Variable Out, Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

Hola quiero crear una variable `OUT` que la utilizaré más adelante, pero me aparece el siguiente error al momento de crear el bloque:

```
DECLARE
@COD_PERI INT, 
@COD_ESTA_LOG INT OUT  

BEGIN
    SET @COD_ESTA_LOG = 5
END
```

> Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 3
>       Incorrect syntax near 'OUT'.

Answer (score 4):

A no ser que estés creando un procedimiento almacenado la clausula `OUT` está siendo utilizada de forma incorrecta ya que esta solo se admite para procedimientos almacenados de la forma que la quieres utilizar y en instrucciones `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` Y `MERGE` de acuerdo a la documentación oficial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/ms177564.aspx

Lo que puedes hacer es crear el procedimiento almacenado:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MiProcedimiento
@COD_PERI INT, 
@COD_ESTA_LOG INT OUT  
AS
BEGIN

SET @COD_ESTA_LOG = 5

END
```

Y mandarlo llamar si es desde SQL:

```
exec MiProcedimiento @COD_PERI, @COD_ESTA_LOG OUTPUT
```

O desde el lenguaje de programacion en el que vayas hacer uso del procedimiento.

Comment: En efecto, estoy de acuerdo con tu respuesta :) +1